# Angular - npm: como desistalar o webpack?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, packages

Estou tento problemas com o webpack, gostaria de saber como remover ele, tentei das formas abaixo que são indicadas como exemplos no site da NPM, mas sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você pode simplesmente apagar a pasta `node_modules` dentro do projeto

Comment: ajudou em parte

Comment: provavelmente esses erros que está tendo pode ser relacionado a versão do seu node.js / npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi

- recriar novamente o projeto
- fazer uma instalação limpa do node